# <nav> element doesn't show top padding

Tags: css, html

I am designing a website using HTML5 elements. With the following HTML5 and CSS code, there is some abnormality with the top padding for the menus.

```css
/* CSS Resets */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
 font-size:100%;
 font:inherit;
 vertical-align:baseline;
}
/* CSS Resets end */


/* CSS document starts */

body {
 background-color: #e4deaf;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

nav {
 display: block;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #808080;
 border: 1px dashed black;
 border-radius: 7px;
 padding: 1em 3em;
}
a:hover {
 background-color: #ffbc6a;
}
a:active {
 background-color: #e4deaf;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Menu 1</a>
  <a href="">Menu 2</a>
  <a href="">Menu 3</a>
</nav>
```

[This is the output screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X4xV.png)

What is wrong with the padding of the menus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `inline` default value of `display` property on `a` elements. Try to change with `inline-block` and it works.

```css
/* CSS Resets */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
 font-size:100%;
 font:inherit;
 vertical-align:baseline;
}
/* CSS Resets end */


/* CSS document starts */

body {
 background-color: #e4deaf;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

nav {
 display: block;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #808080;
 border: 1px dashed black;
 border-radius: 7px;
 padding: 1em 3em;
    display: inline-block;
}
a:hover {
 background-color: #ffbc6a;
}
a:active {
 background-color: #e4deaf;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Menu 1</a>
  <a href="">Menu 2</a>
  <a href="">Menu 3</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Better way to construct menu using unordered list <ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

Comment: Thank you.. it worked..... @hungerstar's edit is not in this answer though... I have taken it fromt he comment in the other answer.

Comment: you're welcome, and yes, as @Dolphine said, it's better for semantic to use list with links in your nav menu than just links ;)

Comment: @Dolphine not necessarily. That used to be the standard before HTML5 and the `<nav>` element arrived. What the OP used is becoming more standard these days though could be improved with ARIA in mind to `<nav role="navigation">`.

Comment: They are suggesting `<nav><ul><li><a></a></li><li><a></a></li></ul></nav>`.

Comment: @dolphine Is there any advantage of using <ul> inside the <nav> element. For my eyes, it simply seems very simple to use just <a> elements unless there is some significant advantage of using <ul> inside <nav>.

Comment: @justin Please read this article https://css-tricks.com/wrapup-of-navigation-in-lists/

Comment: @Dolphine Thank you for that link. For other users reading this, this is the direct link to the articles http://www.webaxe.org/leave-accessibility-to-experts-please/ and https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/

Anyway, point understood...